# Deprecation : In PaperClip 4.3.7 with AWS SDK v1 in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, aws-sdk, deprecation-warning

I am using PaperClip gem 4.3.7 , which uploads file to AWS s3 with rails 4.2 version. I get the following deprecation warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: [paperclip] [deprecation] AWS SDK v1 has been deprecated in paperclip 5. Please consider upgrading to AWS 2 before upgrading paperclip.
```

As of now before migrating to Rails 5, I want to remove all the deprecations for rails 4.2 the above is one of which I need to fix. How can i avoid deprecation raising in this same Rails 4.2 version?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/#Installation). You can also consider installing the [Rails version of the SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-rails) which should upgrade you to version 2.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question of what to do in detail.
So keep PaperClip 4.3.x and upgrade AWS SDK? Will that work?

Looks like there is some guidance here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Upgrade-Paperclip-4x-to-5x